# Scala Abstract Type Member

Tags: scala, abstract-type

I noticed that I can instantiate a scala trait with an abstract type member. The code below compiles. But what is the t.B?

```
trait A {
    type B
}

val t = new A {}
```

Comment: You cannot instantiate a trait.

Comment: @I.K. Sure, you can, if you provide definitions for all abstract methods and values. Here A has no def and vals, so you don't have to provide anything. It just works.

Comment: You can't instantiate a trait. What this code does is instantiate an anonymous subclass which extends the trait.

Comment: I know I am extending the trait with an anonymous class. I am instantiating the anonymous class not the trait. I am sorry I skipped a bit in my question. @Kolmar, does it means that if B is not used anywhere in A, then I do not need to provide a concrete type for it?

Comment: @intangible02, "B" in the trait "A" is just a type parameter. You can use to specify the type of other members in A without specifying what that type really is. What are you trying to achieve here? Maybe we can help further if we know.

Comment: My background is C#. In .Net, there is no concept of type member. And a class is abstract if any of its method is abstract. So I just did not understand why the anonymous class can be instantiated when it has an abstract member. Now I know that the type member is different from method member and it can be left without a concrete type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is `t.B`.

```
trait A {
  type B
  def f(b: B)
}

val t = new A { def f(b: B) = {} }

t.f(0)
```

has the error

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Int(0)
required: t.B
```

Types don't have to be "overriden" like methods.

This type is its own thing. It's not very useful, but that's what it is.

Like all other types, it is a subtype of `Any` and a supertype of `Nothing`.

```
Seq[t.B](): Seq[Any]
Seq[Nothing](): Seq[t.b]
```

And that's about all that can be said about it.